# How to detect and dismiss system alert dialog

Tags: android

I have an app that shows video all the time in fullscreen mode. So I have a signle activity and SurfaceView on it. There's no access to the screen or buttons of the device, so all I have is just a monitor showing video.

The problem is that from time to time my mobile operator sends an adverts that open up on device as alert dialog. This dialogs are shown above my activity and I need to dismiss them somehow. Or maybe somehow forbid the system to open this type of dialogs.

Is it possible on android and how to do this?

Comment: Can you modify android source code for the device, i.e. is this custom device manufactured by you?

Comment: If application is third party then you can't. Without source code you can not do it.

Comment: ok thanks! No, this is not my build of Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dismiss dialogs belonging to the system or 3rd party apps, but depending on your setup and needs you do have a couple other solutions:

- programmatically turn of the mobile network connectivity (or put the phone completely into airplane mode) while the video is playing, so you don't get any other data (sms or any other kind) from the network
- when your activity loses focus (`onPause` event), bring it back to focus or relaunch it while preserving current video time

Comment: You say you can't dismiss, but what about detecting it?